How to Stop Element Shifting on Android Chrome Mobile Devices when Fixing the Position with Percentage
How do you stop elements from shifting on Android Chrome mobile devices when the browser auto expands the viewport when you scroll down the page?
I've used the following code to stick an element half way down the screen and it keeps shifting when you scroll down, and when you scroll up.
position: fixed
right: 0
bottom: 50%

Is there any other way I can stick the element to the center of the screen without using percentage?
